# How to add a bootstrap datepicker on a website?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I found the below code from the website mentioned below after my two-days search for a `bootstrap` `datepicker` for my website. Being a newbie I do not know how to implement but I gave it a try, however, I did not get the result as expected, I got only an `inputfield` but no `datepicker`. Can somebody help me implement the code?

I create a `test.html` file in my project and added the below code to test.

NOTE: This is the only code I have for `datepicker`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Site</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- google fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container my-4">
  <div class="md-form">
<input placeholder="Selected date" type="text" id="date-picker-example" class="form-control datepicker">

</div>

</div>

<script>
// Data Picker Initialization
$('.datepicker').pickadate();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Source of the code](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/mdbootstrap/944437#html-tab-view)

Comment: Can somebody help me with it?

Answer (score 3):

In your input tag with id=date-picker-example replace **type field with "date"**. I mean the code of your input field will be like this.

`<input placeholder="Selected date" type="date" id="date-picker-example" class="form-control datepicker">`

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response however if you look at the website I have mentioned at the bottom of my question you will find that this is not how the whole thing looks like. How to achieve that?